Vector of order statistics is sufficient
I was trying to solve the following problem:
Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be i.i.d with some continuous distribution $F$. Show that the vector of order statistics, $(X_{(1)}, \dots, X_{(n)})$ is sufficient for $F$, where $X_{(1)} \leq \cdots \leq X_{(n)}$ is an ordered permutation of the sample of size $n$.
I took a look at the related questions: 1 and 2. But in both cases, $X_i$ has density, which does not occur in my case since $F$ is only continuous.
In the book by Lehmann and Casella (link), the Example $1.6.10$ deals with the case where
$F$ is only continuous. However, the explanations provided did not convince me. I would like a more formal proof; could someone help me?

I don't quite understand your question or where you are stuck.  I would slightly adjust the language to say that you are looking for a sufficient statistic for some parameter $\theta$ of a parametrised family of distributions, i.e. a statistic which might be simpler but which would allow you to make the same inferences about $\theta$ as the original data does.
The original data $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$  is tautologically sufficient as it gives you as much information about $\theta$ as the original data gives you about $\theta$ because these are i.i.d. from a continuous distribution (probability $0$ of ties).
So any of its $n!$ permutations are equally likely (with $n!$ unrelated to $\theta$) and this implies that knowing the ordered observations $(X_{(1)}, \dots, X_{(n)})$ still gives you the same information about $\theta$ and so is also sufficient. You do not care whether the original data before ordering was some other permutation such as $(X_{(2)}, X_{(n)}, \dots, X_{(1)}, X_{(3)})$ or $(X_{(n)}, \dots, X_{(3)}, X_{(2)}, X_{(1)})$ as it cannot affect any inferences about $\theta$.
Likelihood is a more flexible concept than probability or density - for example it does not need to sum or integrate to $1$, but there is a meaningful sense in which you can say that seeing the ordered observations $(X_{(1)}, \dots, X_{(n)})$ is $n!$ times as likely as seeing the original data $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$, since any of the $n!-1$ other equally likely permutations of the original data would also have resulted in you seeing the same ordered data.
